# Input directly user info when query work items

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

When code run into line 2, Windows will show a popup to input username, password for TFS access:

```
TeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(url), new UICredentialsProvider());
TeamProjectCollection.Connect(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.ConnectOptions.IncludeServices);
TeamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
IsConnected = true;
```

Have any way to assign username, password automatically without login from popup of windows.

Thanks.

Comment: When it prompts for credentials, that means that the credentials that the process is running under do not have permission to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to directly insert user credentials and not use the one the process is running, the following worked for me:

```
WindowsCredential credentials = new WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential(username, domain, password), new MyCredentials(username, domain, password));
TfsTeamProjectCollection connectedTPC = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUrl, new TfsClientCredentials(credentials));
```

It's a bit strange to provide credentials two times, but without the MyCredentials I will get no answer from TFS, not sure why.

```
public class MyCredentials : ICredentialsProvider
{
    private NetworkCredential credentials;
    #region ICredentialsProvider Members
    public MyCredentials(string user, string domain, string password)
    {
        credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);
    }

    public ICredentials GetCredentials(Uri uri, ICredentials failedCredentials)
    {
        return credentials;
    }

    public void NotifyCredentialsAuthenticated(Uri uri)
    {
        // who cares
    }

    #endregion
}
```